# Careers text/plain email messages are not formatted correctly

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, jobs

I just created a Careers account, and clicked to verify my email address.  The text/plain portion of the email is formatted with `\r\n` rather than `\n`, so in my unix mail client (mutt), it looks like this:

```
---Attachment: text/plain                                              -- (all)
Thanks for registering with Stack Overflow Careers^M
^M
To ensure that potential employers can reach you via email, we need to confirm
your email address. All it takes is a single click.^M
^M
Click here to verify your email address^M
^M
If the above link is not clickable, copy and paste this link into your web
browser's address bar:^M
^M
 http://careers.stackoverflow.com/email/verify/xxxx/obfuscated ^M
^M
??^M
^M
Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site.^M
^M
stackoverflow.com LLC, 410 Clayton Ave, El Cerrito CA 94530 <3
```

<strike>**Edit:** Okay, there's definitely a difference, but it's now broken in the other direction: now there's no linefeeds at all (in places where there ought to be, e.g. before "Careers Team"); spaces are also absent between sentences. Also note the special character after the URL, third-to-last line.</strike>

```
Thanks for filing your CV with http://careers.stackoverflow.com !We wanted to let you know that we'll be starting the employer beta later today -- and that means potential employers will be checking out your stuff! So, here's our friendly reminder to go in and make sure your CV is looking good before that happens.In particular, here are a few things to watch out for:- Go through your "Where do you want to work" locations and make sure they're accurate and specific. Putting WORLD here is .. less than optimal. Remember, you can have as many potential work locations as you like, and they can be as broad or narrow as you like: zipcodes, cities, regions and states are all valid.- While you're looking your desired work locations, make *sure* you have ticked the "I have the legal right to work in this location" box appropriately for each location. This is a key search field, and it defaults to required for employers. So if it's not filled correctly, you won't show up! - Make sure you've filled in the essential, most often displayed fields at the top of your CV like Full Name, Location, Personal Statement -- along with your likes and dislikes. These are also shown in search results.- Since the earliest beta, we've added full Markdown support to all free text fields, so if you're inclined, you can add bold, bullets, headers, and the full range of Markdown and basic HTML markup to make your text pop.As we ramp up the employer side of the service, we'll keep you advised over the next few weeks with brief emails like this one.If you have any questions or feedback, don't hesitate to email us -- and we're always listening for feedback at http://meta.stackoverflow.com under the [careers] tag.Careers Team---

http://careers.stackoverflow.com�|

This mail was sent by careers.stackoverflow.com. Questions? Comments? Let us know on our feedback site.

stackoverflow.com LLC, 410 Clayton Ave, El Cerrito CA 94530 <3
```

**Edit 2:** Sorry, the "duplicate with fixed formatting" email just rolled in and it looks much better now. :)

Comment: Please disregard the request to remove 'status-completed' -- all is now good, as per my latest edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: we have switched to a [third party email component](http://www.afterlogic.com/products/net-email-components) recommended by our pals at [Doctype](http://doctype.com).

```
X-Mailer: MailBee.NET 5.7.2.156
From: "Stack Overflow"
```

I can confirm that it "fixes" [the quoted-printable encoding bug](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=156052) in the .NET framework.